Checkout Page Not Loading After Upgrading from Magento 2.4.5-p5 to 2.4.6-p7
I recently upgraded my local Magento Enterprise edition from version 2.4.5-p5 to 2.4.6-p7. After resolving some Zend framework-related issues, most functionality is working correctly. However, the checkout page is not loading, and in the console, I’m seeing an error: window.checkoutConfig.quoteData not found.
I’ve checked the block class, but it's returning empty data. Strangely, when I downgrade back to Magento 2.4.6-p5, everything works as expected.
Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Should check the logs under var/log folder

This happens because of changes to Content Security Policy (CSP) to comply with PCI 4.0 requirements. After update the checkout page CSP mode changed from report_only to strict. As a temporary solution you can add the following to your env.php
'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'csp' => [
                'mode' => [
                    'storefront_checkout_index_index' => [
                        'report_only' => '1'
                    ],
                    'admin_sales_order_create_index' => [
                        'report_only' => '1'
                    ]
                ],
                'policies' => [
                    'storefront_checkout_index_index' => [
                        'scripts' => [
                            'inline' => '1'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'admin_sales_order_create_index' => [
                        'scripts' => [
                            'inline' => '1'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

